# Get default value if attribute not set or faulty in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there is a way to get the default value of an attribute that has not been set.

For example in this easy snippet:

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(function(elm){
  console.log(elm.getAttribute('type'));
});
```

```html
<input />
<input type='integer'/><!-- This one is invalid -->
<input type='number'/>
<input type='submit'/>
```

… The result is "null" for the first one, and "integer" for the second.

We all know that without the `type` attribute explicitly defined (or an invalid one, like in my snippet), the `input` is treated by default as a `input type="text"`. But, is there any way to display that?

I mean… Is there any function that would return "text" instead of "null" or the faulty value?
Something that may be used like this: `input.getAttributeOrDefault("type")`?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: `console.log(input.type);`

Comment: You want the property, not the attribute. `input.type`.

Comment: `But we all now that without the type attribute, the default value is text.` Where do you get that from? Without the attribute there is no attribute. The input might be treated by default as a text input by the browser but that's a different story.

Comment: @Nope You're right. That's more or less what I meant. Without this attribute, it works like if it was "text". I wanted to know if there was a way to know that it was inexplicitly set to "text". I'll edit in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default type value if not provided for an input element is 'text'. You can acces it with this :

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');
console.log(input.type);
```

```html
<input />
```

-- EDIT --
Beware integer is not a valid type so it will fallback to text

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(function(elm){
  console.log(elm.type);
});
```

```html
<input />
<input type='integer'/>
<input type='number'/>
<input type='submit'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the input type you can use the following code by using `input.type`

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');
console.log(input.type);
```

```html
<input />
```

**EDIT**

The code using `input.type` works in all the valid cases. `type = "integer"` should be replaced with `type = "number"`. If the type is not recognized as valid by the interpreter then its set to default `text`

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(function(elm){
  console.log(elm.type);
  //console.log(elm.getAttribute('type'));
});
```

```html
<input />
<input type='number'/>
<input type='submit'/>
```